# How to include excluded toolbox m-files in MATLAB compiler

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler, mcc

I want to use Fuzzy Logic Toolbox in C#. To do this, I created a NET-library using deploytool, but it does not include the file fuzzy.m, which I need to work. And in the log mccExcludedFiles.log the following information:

> This file contains the list of various toolbox functions that are not 
>   included in the CTF file. An error will be thrown if any of these functions 
>   are called at run-time. Some of these functions may be from toolboxes 
>   that you are not using in your application. The reason for this is that 
>   these toolboxes have overloaded some methods that are called by your code. 
>   If you know which toolboxes are being used by your code, you can use the -p 
>   flag with the -N flag to list these toolboxes explicitly. This will 
>   cause MATLAB Compiler to only look for functions in the specified toolbox 
>   directories in addition to the MATLAB directories. Refer to the MCC 
>   documentation for more information on this.
>
> C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\fuzzy\fuzzy\fuzzy.m 
>      called by D:\MyFolder\VNTU\bakal\matlabAndCs\ShowFuzzyDesigner.m 
>   (because of toolbox compilability rules)

How do I include this excluded **fuzzy.m** file in the compilation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `fuzzy` launches the Fuzzy Inference Systems editor, a GUI supplied with Fuzzy Logic Toolbox. Compilation of Toolbox GUIs with MATLAB Compiler is typically not supported, and as detailed in the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/supported/compiler_support.html) for MATLAB Compiler, this is true of the GUIs within Fuzzy Logic Toolbox.

I must say, I think the message you're getting in the `mccExcludedFiles.log` file is mostly misleading - all of those things *could* cause a file to have been excluded, but in this case the only relevant bit is at the end, "(because of toolbox compilability rules)".

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into how to build a fuzzy system using the line code functions supplied with the fuzzy toolbox, and not the GUI. [This walkthrough](https://www.mathworks.com/help/fuzzy/working-from-the-command-line.html) gives you a pretty good handle on building a Mamdani inference system using the line code tools. I am not positive how these translate into C# code, but I think there should be equivalent libraries therein.

If you cannot find a natural way to implement the MATLAB routines in C#, then you could look [at this discussion](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/288766) which links some free fuzzy libraries for C#. I think one of the links is broken, but the other three load just fine.